# Meteor accounts-password, display emails of all user

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am new to Meteor. For learning purpose, I just wanted to list the emails of all users. But can only see email for logged in user.

**Notes:**

- I am using Meteor 1.4.2
- I am in development environment. So, I
  haven't removed 'insecure' or 'autopublish'. I know it's a bad
  practice. But this is just for a quick start.

My Template helper looks like:

```
Template.usersList.helpers({
    users () {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'username': 1, emails:1}});
    },
    email(){
        if(typeof this.emails === 'undefined'){
            console.error(this.emails, "Unauthorized Attempt");
            return "--NaN--";
        } else {
            return this.emails[0].address;
        }
    }
});
```

Blaze template:

```
<template name="usersList">
    This is Users List
    <ul>
        {{#each users}}
        <li>{{username}} | {{email}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**In result, it shows Username for all of the users. And only shows email of logged in user. For other users the "emails" array is returned as undefined.**

```
jessica | dad@email.com
Waqas | --NaN--
Bob | --NaN--
```

In above result jessica is logged in user. Can't see other user's email.

Can someone please tell me how to display emails for all users. Or please point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Ahmad

Comment: You should check the `this` variable inside your `email` helper, to see what it is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this on the server:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

And this on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

For more details, see the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users).

Mind you, you probably want to limit what you will eventually actually publish to clients. But I think you get the idea. `Meteor.users` is just a collection, so you can publish from it just like you would from any other collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I had to use pub/sub. So, following worked for me:

// in server

```
Meteor.publish("userList", function () {
       return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1}});
});
```

// in client

```
Meteor.subscribe("userList");
```